# Batch copy metadata (date) from .mpg to .mp4 (touch -r)

Tags: touch

I have a large number of YYMMDD.HHMMSS.mpg files. What I want is to copy the metadata to (the converted) YYMMDD.HHMMSS.mp4 files. 
Can this be done in batch?

touch -r *.mpg *.mp4

Comment: "in batch" meaning each "mp4" file should have a unique time, matching the corresponding "mpg" file, or "batch" meaning every mp4 file should end up with one (arbitrary?) timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in ./*.mpg
do
  touch -r "$f" "${f%.mpg}.mp4"
done
```

... will touch loop over every mpg file and touch the corresponding mp4 file, referencing the mpg file.